# adjust css of gauge element without breaking

Tags: css, vuejs2

I am simply trying to make this gauge smaller. When I try and do that (modify the container class) it warps the whole gauge element. I change the position to relative and the edge of the gauge seems to break. Any ideas on how to scale this without breaking the gauge? I eventually will nest this inside of a column in bootstrap and just trying to get this working on a basic level. Any advice on this css issue would be helpful

```js
const Gauge = Vue.extend({
  template: `
    <div class="container">
      <div class="gauge-bg"></div>
      <div class="gauge-middle"></div>
      <div class="gauge-overlay" :style="{ transform: rotate }"></div>
      <div class="gauge-data">
        <span>{{ percentage }}%</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
  props: ['percentage'],
  computed: {
    rotate() {
      const v = this.percentage * 180 / 100;
      return `rotate(${v}deg)`;
    } } });



new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    Gauge 
  } 
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #4d4d4d;
}
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.gauge-bg {
  z-index: 1;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #a3f6ba;
  border-radius: 250px 250px 0 0;
}
.gauge-middle {
  z-index: 3;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #4d4d4d;
  width: 250px;
  height: calc(250px / 2);
  top: 75px;
  margin-left: 75px;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-radius: 250px 250px 0 0;
}
.gauge-overlay {
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #5df086;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  top: 200px;
  border-radius: 0 0 200px 200px;
  transform-origin: center top;
}
.gauge-data {
  z-index: 4;
  color: #5df086;
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<gauge percentage="33"></gauge>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick and dirty solution is to use `transform: scale()`:

```
.container {
  transform: scale(.5) translateY(-100%);
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
}
```

combined with a font-size increase (optional).

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

const Gauge = Vue.extend({
  template: `
    <div class="container">
      <div class="gauge-bg"></div>
      <div class="gauge-middle"></div>
      <div class="gauge-overlay" :style="{ transform: rotate }"></div>
      <div class="gauge-data">
        <span>{{ percentage }}%</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
  props: ['percentage'],
  computed: {
    rotate() {
      const v = this.percentage * 180 / 100;
      return `rotate(${v}deg)`;
    } } });



new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    Gauge 
  } 
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #4d4d4d;
}
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: scale(.5) translateY(-100%);
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
}
.gauge-bg {
  z-index: 1;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #a3f6ba;
  border-radius: 250px 250px 0 0;
}
.gauge-middle {
  z-index: 3;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #4d4d4d;
  width: 250px;
  height: calc(250px / 2);
  top: 75px;
  margin-left: 75px;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-radius: 250px 250px 0 0;
}
.gauge-overlay {
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #5df086;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  top: 200px;
  border-radius: 0 0 200px 200px;
  transform-origin: center top;
}
.gauge-data {
  z-index: 4;
  color: #5df086;
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 48px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<gauge percentage="33"></gauge>
</div>
```

The proper solution would be to rewrite its CSS so that it takes a variable (`$gaugeWidth` !?) and factors in all its hard-coded sizes so it scales correctly (what the original dev should have done in the first place).